# Функция super() python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class A:
    def __init__():
         print(1)


class B(A):
    def __init__():
         super(A , self).__init__()
         print(2)


obj = B()
```

Почему интерпретатор выводит только в консоль **`2`**, я ожидал увидеть там ещё и **`1`**.

Я не понимаю как работает функция `super()`. Если в данном коде указать эту функцию без аргументов, то все функции `print` успешно будут выведены, а так выводится только **`2`** в консоль.

Объясните как работает функция `super` с аргументами и без?

Comment: а где селф? оно вообще работает?

Comment: @eri Оно еще и неправильно наследует в super

Comment: https://overcoder.net/q/3252/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-python-super-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-init-duplicate

Answer (score 3):

У Вас неправильно выполнено наследование. Функция `super()` может принимать 2 параметра `super([type [, object]])`. Первый аргумент – это тип, к предкам которого мы хотим обратиться. А второй аргумент – это объект, к которому надо привязаться.

Также обязательно требуется указание `self` для конструктора `__init__`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
         print(1)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
         super(B, self).__init__()  # либо super().__init__()
         print(2)


obj = B()
```

Если же Вы используете `super(A, self).__init__()`, то Вы обращаетесь к родителю `A` — простому объекту без `print(1)`

Comment: Более того, в python3 параметры super опциональные. Поэтому лучше использовать `super().__init__()`, т.е. без параметров. Как раз чтобы избежать подобной ошибки.